# Format Text in entire row based upon user input

Tags: excel, vba, formatting

I've got some code that I use to color some text bold and red depending on a user input. The data is in column F. I'd like to color all of the text in that row red, with the exception of column F (so Range of column text formatting = A:E)

I should add, this data is in a data table in excel, I'm not sure if that's relevant.

I'm a beginner in VBA and am unsure about how to address the row when the code deals with a string.

Here's my code

```
    Public Sub RedText()

    Set MyRange = Range("A:F")  'The Range that contains the substring you want to change color

    substr = InputBox("Enter the word to make Red", , "note")

    txtColor = 3   'The ColorIndex which repsents the color you want to change



    For Each myString In MyRange

        lenstr = Len(myString)

        lensubstr = Len(substr)

        For i = 1 To lenstr

            tempString = Mid(myString, i, lensubstr)

            If tempString = substr Then

                myString.Characters(Start:=i, Length:=lensubstr).Font.ColorIndex = txtColor

                myString.Characters(Start:=i, Length:=lensubstr).Font.Bold = True

            End If

         Next i

    Next myString

End Sub
```

I've tried adding statements like r.Interior.Color = vbYellow for the range but I can't even begin to get it to work. Can someone point me in the right direction?

thanks in advance

Comment: why not use Conditional Formatting?

Comment: Because the report is dynamic and what needs to be highlighted is only a substring of what's in a cell. So, I want to get user input on what substring needs to be formatted in the column, then format the rest of the row minus the original column.

Comment: Then loop the F column and use: `myString.Offset(,-5).Resize(1,5).interior.color = vbYellow` inside the if.

Comment: Thank you! Worked like a charm.